# searchable activity, handle event

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest

In an Android's search activity, is it possible to handle the event when the user touches the cross button to clear the search box?
The button I'm talking about is the cross in the screenshot:

[image: Searchable activity bar]

This is the definition on the manifest:

```
   <activity 
        android:name=".MySearchActivity" 
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
                   android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
    </activity>
```

This is the xml referenced on the meta-data:

```
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint" />
```

Comment: did you try OnQueryTextListener?

Comment: Thanks @pskink it works fine, that responds the question, (you can add it as a comment so I can accept the response)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use SearchView.OnQueryTextListener interface, in particular see onQueryTextChange(String newText) method